# select latest Table in a Big Query Dataset - Standard SQL syntax

Tags: google-bigquery

I have dataset containing multiple tables with similar names:

e.g.

*affilinet_4221_first_20180911_204956

affilinet_4221_first_20180911_160004

affilinet_4221_first_20180911_085559

affilinet_4221_first_20180910_201323

affilinet_4221_first_20180910_201042

affilinet_4221_first_20180910_080006

affilinet_4221_first_20180909_160707*

This query identifies the latest dataset (according to yyyymmdd_hhmmss naming convention) with **__TABLES_SUMMARY__** method

```
SELECT max(table_id) as table_id FROM `modemutti-8d8a6.feed_first.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
where table_id LIKE "affilinet_4221_first_%"
```

[query result](https://screencast.com/t/B1ZcR1V6E9)

this query extracts all values from a specific table with **_TABLE_SUFFIX** method

```
SELECT * FROM `modemutti-8d8a6.feed_first.*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = "affilinet_4221_first_20180911_204956"
```

[query result](https://screencast.com/t/RaGHo7xZlr)

This query combines **__TABLES_SUMMARY__** (which returns `affilinet_4221_first_20180911_204956`) and **_TABLE_SUFFIX**

```
SELECT * FROM `modemutti-8d8a6.feed_first.*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = (
            SELECT max(table_id) FROM `modemutti-8d8a6.feed_first.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
            where table_id LIKE "affilinet_4221_first_%")
```

this query fails:

> Error: Cannot read field 'modemio_cat_level' of type INT64 as STRING

[error screenshot](https://screencast.com/t/UD9JAgImBkat)

any idea why is this happening or how I could solve the issue?

------------EDIT------------

@Mikhail solution works correctly but processes a huge amount of data. See [explicit call](https://www.screencast.com/t/RaGHo7xZlr) Vs the [suggested Method](https://screencast.com/t/fK9lbWIfXJsE). Another solution would have been

```
SELECT * FROM  `modemutti-8d8a6.feed_first.affilinet_4221_first_*` WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = 
    ( 
    SELECT MAX(_TABLE_SUFFIX)  FROM`modemutti-8d8a6.feed_first.affilinet_4221_first_*`
    )
```

but  [this](https://screencast.com/t/1bo8ufe1) processes also a much bigger amount of data compared to the **explicit query**. Is there are way to achieve through a view in the UI or should I rather use the Python / Java SDK via API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM `modemutti-8d8a6.feed_first.affilinet_4221_first_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = (
    SELECT REPLACE(MAX(table_id), 'affilinet_4221_first_', '') 
    FROM `modemutti-8d8a6.feed_first.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
    WHERE table_id LIKE "affilinet_4221_first_%"
)
```

Comment: this is expected and definitely not suggested rather just answering your question on how to solve the specific issue that you described in your question!